# Python: check if any word in a list of words matches any pattern in a list of regular expression patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a long list of words and [regular expression patterns](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in a .txt file, which I read in like this:

```
with open(fileName, "r") as f1:
    pattern_list = f1.read().split('\n')
```

for illustration, the first seven look like this:

```
print pattern_list[:7] 
# ['abandon*', 'abuse*', 'abusi*', 'aching', 'advers*', 'afraid', 'aggress*']
```

I want to know whenever I match a word from an input string to any of the words/patterns in pattern_list. The below *sort of* works, but I see two problems:

1. First, it seems pretty inefficient to re.compile() every item in my    pattern_list every time I inspect a new string_input... but when I    tried to store the re.compile(raw_str) objects in a list (to then be    able to reuse the already compiled regex list for something more like    `if w in regex_compile_list:`, it didn't work right.)
2. Second, it sometimes doesn't work as I expect - notice how

   - abuse* matched with abusive
   - abusi* matched with abused and abuse
   - ache* matched with aching

What am I doing wrong, and how can I be more efficient?  Thanks in advance for your patience with a noob, and thanks for any insight!

```
string_input = "People who have been abandoned or abused will often be afraid of adversarial, abusive, or aggressive behavior. They are aching to abandon the abuse and aggression."
for raw_str in pattern_list:
    pat = re.compile(raw_str)
    for w in string_input.split():
        if pat.match(w):
            print "matched:", raw_str, "with:", w
#matched: abandon* with: abandoned
#matched: abandon* with: abandon
#matched: abuse* with: abused
#matched: abuse* with: abusive,
#matched: abuse* with: abuse
#matched: abusi* with: abused
#matched: abusi* with: abusive,
#matched: abusi* with: abuse
#matched: ache* with: aching
#matched: aching with: aching
#matched: advers* with: adversarial,
#matched: afraid with: afraid
#matched: aggress* with: aggressive
#matched: aggress* with: aggression.
```

Comment: A note: the regex "abuse*" matches "abus" followed by zero or more "e" characters. The regex syntax is not the same as shell wildcards. (It seems like you might mean something like: "abuse.*")

Comment: Yeah, these aren't regexes! (If they only contain `[a-z]` and `*`, though, you could make them into regexes using some string operations: `"abandon*` would become `"^abandon.*$"`.)

Comment: That kind of wildcard pattern should be matched using [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) I presume.

Comment: Depending on the size of the text file, it may make more sense to read in to a single string(rather than individually) and then run the `pat.findall` against the entire string and parse the resulting array.

Comment: @svk: that explains it.  regex vs. shell wildcard dif = good to know, thanks so much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For matching shell-style wildcards you could (ab)use the module [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch)

As `fnmatch` is primary designed for filename comparaison, the test will be case sensitive or not depending your operating system. So you'll have to normalize both the text and the pattern (here, I use `lower()` for that purpose)

```
>>> import fnmatch

>>> pattern_list = ['abandon*', 'abuse*', 'abusi*', 'aching', 'advers*', 'afraid', 'aggress*']
>>> string_input = "People who have been abandoned or abused will often be afraid of adversarial, abusive, or aggressive behavior. They are aching to abandon the abuse and aggression."


>>> for pattern in pattern_list:
...     l = fnmatch.filter(string_input.split(), pattern)
...     if l:
...             print pattern, "match", l
```

Producing:

```
abandon* match ['abandoned', 'abandon']
abuse* match ['abused', 'abuse']
abusi* match ['abusive,']
aching match ['aching']
advers* match ['adversarial,']
afraid match ['afraid']
aggress* match ['aggressive', 'aggression.']
```

Answer (score 2):

`abandon*` will match `abandonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn`, and not `abandonasfdsafdasf`. You want

```
abandon.*
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the `*`s are all at the end of strings, you might want to do something like this instead:

```
for pat in pattern_list:
    for w in words:
        if pat[-1] == '*' and w.startswith(pat[:-1]) or w == pat:
            # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

If the patterns were using the regex syntax:

```
m = re.search(r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(patterns)), input_string)
if m:
    # found match
```

Use `(?:\s+|^)` and `(?:\s+|$)` instead of `\b` if words are space-separated.